How to catch the "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" error
I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application in .NET Framework 4.7.2 using C#. I have several views containing edit forms. Now if a user enters HTML into one of the text fields, the system throws an error

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

I am aware that I could suppress this action by dressing the corresponding property with the [AllowHtml] attribute in the class definition. However, I do not wish to do this - I just want to catch the error and deal with it in a user-friendly manner.
The problem is, the error seems to be thrown before the flow of control ever gets to the endpoint code in the controller, so the try/catch blocks I have there cannot catch the error. Specifically, a typical endpoint processing a POST request looks like this
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditModel(Model model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.Update())
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ViewModel", "Admin", new { id = model.ID });
                }

                return View("Error", new MyError
                {
                    Message = "Could not update object."
                });
            }

            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return View("Error", new MyError
            {
                Message = e.Message
            });
        }
    }

To reiterate, the problem is that the error is thrown before flow of control reaches this.
How then can I catch this error in the code? Ideally, I'd like to be able to give a short error message on the form in the validation summary.
